# How to define function names with special characters in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function

I want to make a function with the name '~' So it would be like this:

`def ~(*args):`

but it's giving me syntax errors, how do I fix this?

by the way, I've tried `def '~'(*args)` and it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't. Pick a different name.

Comment: If you're desperate: `f = {'~' : lambda *args, **kwargs: ...}` and `f['~'](..)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't: '~' is not a valid character for a Python identifier.

From the [Python docs on (2.3. Identifiers and keywords)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), '~' is ASCII 0x7E which is inside the range U+0001..U+007F where the valid characters are restricted to the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9. This is because some of the other characters from this range are used for other parts of the language's syntax (e.g. the operators `+`, `-` and, indeed `~`: the bitwise complement)

Python 3 does allow Unicode identifiers from outside this range, so (if you really have to) you can use a single Unicode character, e.g.

```
def ϖ(*args):
    ...
```

But, of course, it is harder to write code using characters that aren't on your keyboard.

As Jean-François Fabre has written in his answer, you can do something similar to what you want if you're prepared to change the calling syntax a little: declare a class that is initialized with your arguments and override the `~` operator (using `__invert__`) as your function. For example:

```
class Z:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def __invert__(self):
        print('args are:', self.args)
        # ... do something with args

In [3]: ~( Z(4,5) )
args are: (4, 5)
```

But here you have to pretend to be inverting an instance of your `Z` class instead of calling a function with a tuple of arguments. This doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: Your most recent edit is identical to JFF's answer, which I think is a little unfair to that user to add the same content to your answer.

Comment: Right you are. I wrote my own edit before reading the other answer – I've credited Jean-François, but I'll keep my edit because I think it gives a bit more explanation and makes it clearer that you can make `~` do something other than invert something.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate your level headed response.

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll keep it in mind (I may not be able to use this because I am using a API that may not let me do this)

Answer (score 3):

You can't but in the case of objects, you can define [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) to redefine most operators when applied on custom classes

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def __invert__(self):
        return ~self.x

a = Test(12)
print(~a)
```

I get 2's complement of 12: `-13` because I defined the special `__invert__` function which is called when applying `~` on my custom object.